# Google map directions button without iFrame

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i want to show directions button on map just like if i use the iframe. I have seen many question regarding this, but all of them tell to add direction button `from here` `to here`. But i want the functionality like iframe google map, when you click on direction button it opens the google map and you input your location and you can see the direction then like showed in this website https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/google-maps/.
I want to achieve this functionality using JS.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls) does not have the specific UI control that would open the directions through Google Maps(maps.google.com) native web application. Maps JavaScript API has its own [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) which directly handles the rendering of Directions API requests into your JS maps.

Currently the UI controls available for Maps JavaScript API are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlModification).

If you wish to add this UI control for Maps JavaScript API, you can file a feature request for this on their [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **smga08** answer but this can be done with your own custom implementation and with the use of **Maps URLs**.

I was able to achieve this using Javascript and **[Google Maps Platform Map URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide)**.

In the sample demonstration below, the **destination** is currently set to **"Manhattan New York, NY, USA"** **for sample purposes**.

I've used **[Google Maps Platform Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)** to use the destination's placeid and to parse the returned **address_components**, **geometry.location** for the **[Google Maps Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)** and the **formatted_address**.

I have attached an event listener to this **id:getDirection** to call the window.open function with the Maps URLs on it. The **[URI encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp)** formatted_address is set as  **destination** parameter and I did not put the **origin** parameter so you can add it your self once the Google Maps page opened.

Here's the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }

      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .container {
        width: 100%;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
        display:block;  
        padding:20px;  
        box-sizing:border-box;  
      }  
      .mapContainer {
        width:100%;
        padding:10px;
        border:solid 1px #444;
        height: 500px;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
        display:block;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        position: relative;  
      }  
      .floatingPanel {
        width: 300px;
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        padding:10px;  
        position:absolute;
        top:20px;
        left: 20px;
        z-index:100;  
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #888888;   
      }  
      .floatingPanel > ul {
        width:100%;
        float:left;
        display:block;
        overflow:hidden;  
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }  
      .floatingPanel > ul > li.left {
        width:60%;
        display:inline-block;  
        float:left;  
      }  
      .floatingPanel > ul > li.right {
        width:30%;
        display:inline-block;  
        float:right;  
        cursor:pointer;  
      }          
      .directionIcon {
        background-image: url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/embed/images/entity11_hdpi.png);
        background-size: 70px 210px;
        width:21px;
        height:21px;
        float:none;  
        margin: auto; 
        display:block;  
      }  
      .directionLabel {
        width:100%;
        text-align:center; 
        margin:0;
        padding: 5px 0;
        color:#3a84df;
        font: 400 11px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;  
      }  
      .destinationLabel > h3 {
        font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight:500;  
        color:#000;
        padding:0;
        margin: 0;  
      }  
      .destinationLabel > p {
        font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;      
        color: #5B5B5B;
        font-size:12px;
        line-height: 1px;
      }  
    </style>
    <script>
      (function(exports) {
        "use strict";
          
        var latLng = {lat: 40.7830603, lng: -73.9712488};

        function initMap() {
          exports.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: latLng,
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeControl: false
          });
          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          geocoder.geocode(
            {
              placeId: 'ChIJYeZuBI9YwokRjMDs_IEyCwo'
            },
            function(results, status) {
              if (status === "OK") {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: results[0].geometry.location
                }); 
                var template = '';
                template += '<h3>' + results[0].address_components[0].long_name + '</h3>'; 
                template += '<p>' + results[0].address_components[3].long_name + ', ' + results[0].address_components[4].short_name + '</p>';  
                var holder1 = document.createElement("H3");                 
                var textnode1 = document.createTextNode(results[0].address_components[0].long_name);         
                holder1.appendChild(textnode1);
                var holder2 = document.createElement("p");                 
                var textnode2 = document.createTextNode(results[0].address_components[3].long_name + ', ' + results[0].address_components[4].short_name);         
                holder2.appendChild(textnode2);                  
                document.getElementById("destinationLabel").appendChild(holder1); 
                document.getElementById("destinationLabel").appendChild(holder2);  
                document.getElementById("getDirection").addEventListener("click", function() {
                  window.open('https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination='+encodeURI(results[0].formatted_address));
                });  
              }
            }
          );  
            
        }

        exports.initMap = initMap;
      })((this.window = this.window || {}));
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="mapContainer">
              <div class="floatingPanel">
                  <ul>
                      <li class="left">
                          <div class="destinationLabel" id="destinationLabel">
                          
                          </div>
                      </li>
                      <li class="right">
                            <a class="directionIcon" id="getDirection"></a>
                            <p class="directionLabel">Directions</p>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>              
               <div id="map"></div>
          </div>        
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this answer finds you helpful and good luck on your application!